# Why would file checksums inconsistently fail?

Tags: filesystems, checksum, disk

I created a `~2MiB` file.

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=file.bin bs=2M count=1
```

Then I copied that file a large number of times and generated a checksum for each (identical) copy.

```
for i in `seq 50000`;
do
  name="file.${i}.bin"
  cp file.bin "${name}"
  sha512sum "${name}" > "${name}.sha512"
done
```

I then verified all of those checksummed files with a validation script to run `sha512sum` against each file.

```
for file in `find . -regex ".*\.sha512"`
do
    sha512sum --check --quiet "${file}" || (
      cat "${file}" && sha512sum "${file%.sha512}"
    )
done
```

I **just created these files**, and when I validate them moments later, I see intermittent failures and inconsistencies in the data (console text truncated for readability)

```
will:/mnt/usb $ for file in `find ...
file.5602.bin: FAILED
sha512sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
91fc201a3812e93ef3d4890 ... file.5602.bin
b176e8e3ea63a223130f3a0 ... ./file.5602.bin
```

The checksum files are *all identical since the source files are all identical*

The problem seems to be that my computer is, seemingly at random, generating the **wrong checksum** for some of my files when I go to validate. A **different file** fails the checksum every time, and files that previously failed will pass.

```
will:/mnt/usb $ for file in `find ...
sha512sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
91fc201a3812e93ef3d4890 ... file.3248.bin
442a1d8805ed134c9ab5252 ... ./file.3248.bin
```

Keep in mind that **all of these files are identical**.

I see the same behavior with SATA SSD and HDD, and USB devices, with md5 and sha512, with xfs, btrfs, ext4, and vfat. I tried live booting to another OS. I see this same stranger behavior regardless. I also see `rsync --checksum` for these files thinks checksums are wrong and re-copies these files even though they have not changed.

What could explain this behavior? Since it's happening on multiple devices with all the scenarios I described, I doubt this is bit rot. My kernel logs show no obvious errors. I would assume this is a hardware issue based on my troubleshooting, but how can this be diagnosed? Is it the CPU, the motherboard, the RAM?

Comment: I replaced my PSU as [I'd read](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=1134345) that could be a source of problems with failing hard drives, but I see no difference in behavior.

Comment: Sometimes my verify process seems to not find the files at all. `sha512sum: file.6707.bin: Input/output error`

Comment: I ran the [Intel CPU diagnostic](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool) (after fixing a [bug](https://github.com/JimmyAppelt/Snaz/wiki/Solving-warning-or-error-within-System-Info), `lodctr /R`) and the Intel tests gave me a passing result with no errors.

Comment: I have no BIOS diagnostic utils I can find in my system's menus, and [ASUS (my MOBO maker) has docs for a "PC Diagnostic Tool"](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1011117/), but they don't seem to host that tool any more. I found a download of that tool on an unreliable download site, but it didn't report any errors. My [H87I-PLUS Motherboard seems to have some sort of utility program](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/H87IPLUS/HelpDesk_Download/), but it won't run and seems to just be a fan speed sort of utility from what I've read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What could explain this behavior?** **How can this be diagnosed?**

From what I've read, a number of issues could explain this behavior. Bad disk(s), bad PSU (power supply), bad RAM, filesystem issues.

I tried the following to determine what was happening. I repeated the experiment with different...

- Disks
- Types of disks (SDD vs HDD)
- External drives (3.5 and 2.5 enclosures)
- Flash drives (USB 2 and 3 on various ports)
- Filesystems (ext4, vfat (fat32), xfs, btrfs)
- Different PSU
- Different OS (live boot)

Nothing seemed to resolve this.

Finally, I gave [memtest86+ v5.0.1](http://www.memtest.org/) a try via an Ubuntu live USB.

**voila**. It found bad memory. Through process of elimination I determined one of my memory sticks was bad, and then tested the other over night to ensure it was in good shape. I re-ran my experiment again and I am seeing consistent checksums on all my files.

[image: failing memory in memtest86+]

What a subtle bug. I only noticed this bad behavior by accident. If I hadn't been messing around with file checksums, I do not think I would have found this bad RAM.

This makes me want to regularly schedule a routine in which I verify and test my RAM. A consequence of this bad memory stick is that some of my test data **did end up corrupt**, but more often than not, the checksum verifications were just interimmitent failures.

In one sample data pool, all the checksums start with `cb2848ca0e1ff27202a309408ec76...`, because all ~50,000 files are identical.

Though, there are two files that **are corrupt**, but this **is not bit rot or file integrity damage**.

What seems most likely is that these files were **created with corruption** because `cp` encountered bad RAM when I created these files. Those files consistently return bad checksums of `58fe24f0e00229e8399dc6668b9...` and `bd85b51065ce5ec31ad7ebf3...`, while the other 49,998 files return the same checksum.

This has been a <strike>fun</strike> extremely frustrating experiment in debugging.

Comment: Hats off to not giving up and the detailed feedback.